# SQL Database Primary Key disappears from couple tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

SQL Database Primary Key disappears from couple tables.  I don't know the core reason why this happened I'm still investigating it. In mean time maybe someone had similar problem, because nobody did remove them. So far I think it’s kind of related LINQ to Entity model it could happen but I’m not sure why.

I got the error below as the matter of fact it was working properly before

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'TableName' because it has a DefiningQuery and no element exists in the element to support the current operation
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check source control. You do use source control right?

Comment: same happened over here. we put them back a few weeks ago and they have gone disappearing again. if anyone knows why this happens, it be nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server replication does not produce primary keys when creating tables.  If there's a replication job that recreates these tables, that'd be the problem.